# Hex private ecdsa key to PEM File library

Tags: cryptography, openssl, python, ecc

I am trying to convert a raw private ecdsa key in hex format (k) to a PEM file. I searched for few hours, but couldn't find a suitable library(Python prefered). I am using python-ecdsa but I there is just a function to parse r,s out of signatures.
Do you know any library that is capable of doing that?

Comment: How about pyOpenSSL ?

Comment: As far is I know there is no OpenSSL command that can do the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution now. You can simply use:

```
private_key = SigningKey.from_secret_exponent(k, curve=...)
```

After that you can call functions like priv.to_pem()